# Why is my output voltage offset of 4.5 Volts?

Tags: voltage, operational-amplifier

When using an LM386 amplifier with  an internal gain set to 20, it is powered by Vcc equaling 9 V. My input is a short sound as seen in the graph as the green line. My output is the blue line.

Why is the output offset from the input voltage?

[image: Circuit]

Comment: what kind of opamp? Link to a datasheet. And are you using a x10 scope probe? 
 Wild guess : LM386 (which is not an opamp) and yes, so that is 4V (or half the supply) not 0.4V. That's just what a single rail audio power amp does.

Comment: Op-amps do not have internal gain settings. My guess is that you aren't using a conventional op-amp or even an op-amp at all.

Comment: And what is your source coupling? A unipolar supply amp should not be able to directly accept a bipolar signal properly.

Comment: the operational amplifier used is the LM386

Comment: The LM386 is a *Low Voltage Audio Power Amplifier* - it isn't an op-amp. You need to show your complete circuit.

Comment: What is your intention with the diodes D1-D4? D1 & D3 do absolutely nothing and D2 & D4 are wired in parallel to each other. You could remove both D1 & D3 as well as either D2 or D4 and the behavior would be identical.

Comment: In fact you could remove all of them unless all you're looking for is a 0.6V drop... They really serve no other purpose.

Answer (score 3):

As per the first page on the datasheet for the LM386.:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the answer. The 0.4 volts was a typo.